# How to setup Terraform GCP PostgreSQL DB with private IP on default network

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to setup a PostgreSQL DB on GCP using terraform with a private IP on the default network. See following of GCP GUI equivalent setting:

[image]

I have deployed successfully this example but it creates a new vpc network `private-network`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#private-ip-instance

But I do not wish to create a new private network, and I just want to use the "default" one defined with the VPC. Every configuration I have tried within terraform usually results in either (1) wrong syntax, or (2) default network already exists therefore cannot be created.

```
data "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "default-us-west1"
}
        
resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  provider      = google
  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = data.google_compute_network.default.id
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  provider                = google
  network                 = data.google_compute_network.default.id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name]
}

resource "random_id" "db_name_suffix" {
  byte_length = 4
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "main" {
  name             = "test-db"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_12"
  region           = "us-west1"
  
  depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection] 

  settings {
    availability_type = "REGIONAL"
    tier              = "db-custom-2-8192"
    disk_size         = "10"
    disk_type         = "PD_SSD"
    disk_autoresize   = "true"
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = "false"
      private_network = data.google_compute_network.default.id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried, even the one that results in an error?

Comment: Added my most recent attempt.

Comment: Ah, ok, so when you are using resources you are basically creating a new network. Does the default network exist out of the box with GCP? If so, you might be able to query it with a data source.

Comment: For reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_network.

Comment: Ah I did not previously know I can reference existing resources like that. I am still having trouble getting the syntax. I have tried to reference the default network as: `data.google_compute_network.default.id`, and `google_compute_network.default.id` with no luck. See the edited code block in the original post.

Comment: Ok, so the way this is referenced is that you also have to use the `data` prefix, i.e., `data.google_compute_network.default.id`. What happens when you provide that? Are there any errors? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: Ah, so the documentation says that you have to have a `depends_on` meta-argument when deploying the SQL DB instance: `depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection]`

Comment: Updated the code block in relation to the following error:
`18:   network                 = data.google_compute_network.default.id`
`The argument "network" is required, but no definition was found.`

Comment: Ok, and are you sure that is the name of the default network? Can you check that somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original post used the resource for GCP network. Using resource blocks always creates a new resource instead of using the one that is already present. To poll the information about the resources that already exist, it is always a good idea to use `data` sources [1]. The problem here seems to be that GCP did not complain about creating another network named `default`. In AWS for example if you were to try that, there would be an error and you would know what the reason for the error was. So, to fix the issue with creating a DB in the default network provided by GCP it is enough to use the `data` source but the name of the network has to be correct. As per conversation in the comments, the `data` source block should look like:

```
data "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "default"
}
```

Then, since this data source outputs `id` as an attribute [2], it is enough to reference that value everywhere where it is required with:

```
data.google_compute_network.default.id
```

Additionally, the documentation for the SQL DB says that the `depends_on` meta-argument has to be used [3]:

> For private IP instance setup, note that the `google_sql_database_instance` does not actually interpolate values from `google_service_networking_connection`. You must explicitly add a `depends_on` reference as shown below.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_network#id

[3] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#private-ip-instance